# Google protocol buffers with loadrunner

Tags: web-services, tomcat, protocol-buffers, loadrunner

I have a java web server that encoding the results to protocol buffers.
and my web client already decoding this info to real data.

we already testing these webserives via hp loadrunner performance tool.
we want to avoid creating duplicates of the webservices, so we want to connect the load runner to our proto classes to auto decode the data.

can any body suggest a solutions?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a Google Buffer DFE for LoadRunner, unfortunately such DFE doesn't exist yet so you can either develop this DFE on your own (and maybe share on HPLN in LR 11.52) and then everyone can enjoy it. Or write some manual code in C to do it (also publishable on HPLN).

You can try to check HPLN to see if anyone already implemented it but I doubt it.

It is always a good idea to check the LR support forum here:
http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Forum/bd-p/sws-LoadRunner_SF